# What to do after an assert is raised? What about in release mode

Tags: c++, assert

As far as I understand `assert()` by default is only called in debug mode. If this is not true then my 1st question does not matter.

A simple example

```
#include <cassert>
void my_function(int a) {
  assert(a > 0);
  // Do other stuff
}
```

So my questions are:

1. If the assert() is only called/used in debug mode, do I need to then include a `if (a > 0)` as well as the assert so I catch the condition in release mode? Is that generally the "correct" or "best practice" approach

```
void my_function(int a) {
  assert(a > 0);
  if (a < 0) {
    // Error condition stuff
  }
  // Do other stuff
}
```

2. What should I do when an assert is raised? General error code handling approach? So make `my_function` return an error/success flag?

Comment: One usually either handles the bad case, or asserts it doesn't happen. I can't think of a reason to do both

Comment: If an assert is raised, it indicates that the program is buggy; you should debug your program so that in future builds the assertion failure no longer occurs (or if the assertion failure is a false-positive, modify or remove the `assert()` call)

Comment: @MooingDuck that's what I was leaning to, just handle the case (no assert), seemed wasteful to do it twice, but that left me wondering why use the assert

Comment: An assert kills a program dead in debug mode, forcing you to find and fix the mistake that lead to the assert. You don't do an assert over things that could happen and need to be checked for, you use an assert to prove that you're right and they never happen.

Comment: I add asserts in Visual Studio for conditions that should never happen. When it asserts it breaks into the debugger on that exact line of code so that I can attempt to figure out how it got in that condition to fix my bug.

Comment: `<cassert>` is one of the few *idempotent* header files, which means you can `#undef NDEBUG` then `#include <cassert>` in your code, and it will enable the `assert` behavior, regardless if you are in a *release* or *debug* build.  Makes it selective, when needed (which is very infrequent for me).

Answer (score 3):

> by default is only called in debug mode

To clarify a bit, the standard `assert` is called if and only if the macro `NDEBUG` isn't defined. This can typically be defined or undefined independently of other compiler options that may affect debugging.

> do I need to then include a if (a > 0) as well as the assert so I catch the condition in release mode?

If you want to check something whether `NDEBUG` is defined or not, then you probably shouldn't be using the `assert` at all. You should just be using an `if`.

---

> What should I do when an assert is raised?

The standard `assert` prints information about the location of the assert failure, and terminates the program.

There are many alternative ways to handle errors and there is no one "correct" or "best" practice that suits all use cases. Here are a few:

- One easy choice is to throw an exception. This allows a caller to deal with the failure without making it necessary for every caller to explicitly handle the failure in cases where they cannot handle it.
- Do what the standard macro does: Print (or log) details and terminate.
- Something along the lines of the proposed std::expected in the proposal [P0323](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0323r7.html).

Answer (score 3):

`assert` is usually used to catch a 'this should never happen' error, and such errors are not usually recoverable.  It therefore follows that testing the same condition with an `if` statement is counter-productive.  Just fix the cause of the `assert` (if it ever happens) and move on.

This might sound strange, but I leave asserts enabled in my Release builds.  I then have a robust 'report back to base' reporting mechanism should my program crash and that helps me fix the bug.  A little short-term pain for one customer delivers a better service, overall.

This also ensures that the program doesn't try to stagger on in a broken state, which is important, and reports the error as close to the point of failure as possible.